# Does an object need to know if it's lazy loaded before accessing child

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

Let's say we have an `Invoice` object with `InvoiceRow` child-objects as an **Entity Framework** model.

Now we add a method to the `Invoice`-model that requires access to the rows, for example:

```
invoice.Sum()
```

If the rows are not explicit loaded with the invoice this method `Sum()` will fail. **What is the best way to handle this?**

Should you just 'have to remember' to `include` the child objects when loading the entity? Or should the `Sum()`-method itself explicitly load the childs if `null`? You could also do a new query on the database in the `Sum()`-method and include child-objects there but what if there are unsaved changes?

Comment: it depends on what you want. Both ways work. Do you want to reduce the number of queries against your database? Do you want to minimize loaded data? Do you want to use Linq to Entities `Sum` method? It all depends on what *you* want.

Comment: I can think of no way for Sum() to explicitly load the child-objects so if lazy loading is switched off and the child-objects were not explicitly loaded prior to calling Sum() then the method will fail.

Comment: @ChrisWyatt you can do a new query and load the `InvoiceRow`s based on the `Invoice.Id`

Comment: @Default Would that not require the Invoice object to have a reference to the DbContext?

Comment: @ChrisWyatt no, not really. I'm not saying to populate the `InvoiceRow`s for the existing `Invoice`, but you can load the rows undependently from the Invoice and just sum them, however you want. Basically `var rows = context.InvoiceRows.Where(ir => ir.InvoiceId == loadedInvoice.Id);`

Comment: @Default Right, so you agree with me then, there's no way to do it from within the Sum() method on Invoice without Sum() having access to the context (which it shouldn't). The best approach here is to either ensure the rows will always be available or not do the Sum() operation in Invoice.

Comment: @ChrisWyatt, The problem with independently loading rows is that you miss unsaved changes. It will also costs extra queries to save and requery. I think indeed, the best way is to ensure the rows are just loaded but I'm curious for other opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking for solutions to problems like this, keep in mind Separation of Concerns. I wouldn't want the `Invoice` to require access to the DbContext, but it's fine for it to know whether or not it has the appropriate rows loaded (maybe via `Any()`).

As pointed out in the comments, it really can depend on your particular use case. You have a couple of options:

1. Have a `Sum()` method on the `Invoice` object itself, which sums whatever is available at the time. This could return 0 or throw if there are no child rows, depending on what you need. Whether or not to `Include` here is optional: if your data is fairly static, I would include the details when pulling the `Invoice`. Use a data access layer (or some equivalent) so you aren't pulling an invoice out of storage in different methods. If your data is frequently changing, this approach might not work.
2. Use a separate business object that has an `Invoice`, and is responsible for going to get the detail rows and summing them. This would check either a repository or the database to make sure it has up to date information, and is more useful if it's likely that your data has changed since you first fetched the `Invoice`.

Regarding your last question, "What if there are unsaved changes?": you have to make a business decision here. Since this example is an invoice, there are two reasons I can see for summing: to get a temporary total (think visiting your shopping cart to see how much you've spent so far) or to get the final approved total (checking out). For the first, it's probably OK to warn users that there are or may be unsaved changes that affect the sum total. For the second, you can't allow unsaved changes: you're going to need something to go check for them. You should force users to either commit or discard pending changes before the invoice is finalized.